# Serializing with Jackson (JSON) - getting "No serializer found"?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I get the an exception when trying to serialize a very simple object using Jackson. The error:

> org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for
>   class MyPackage.TestA and no properties
>   discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable
>   SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )

Below is the simple class and code to serialize.

Can anyone tell my why I get this error?

```
public class TestA {
    String SomeString = "asd";
}

TestA testA = new TestA();
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    String testAString = om.writeValueAsString(testA); // error here!

    TestA newTestA = om.readValue(testAString, TestA.class);
} catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I wrote a post about [How to Write a Custom Serializer with Jackson](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/07/01/custom-serializer-jackson/?utm_source=stack-overflow-ao&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=custom-serializer-jackson) that may be helpful to some.

Answer (score 452, accepted):

As already described, the default configuration of an `ObjectMapper` instance is to only access properties that are public fields or have public getters/setters.  An alternative to changing the class definition to make a field public or to provide a public getter/setter is to specify (to the underlying `VisibilityChecker`) a different property visibility rule.  Jackson 1.9 provides the `ObjectMapper.setVisibility()` convenience method for doing so.  For the example in the original question, I'd likely configure this as

```
myObjectMapper.setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
```

For Jackson >2.0:

```
myObjectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
```

For more information and details on related configuration options, I recommend reviewing [the JavaDocs on `ObjectMapper.setVisibility()`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#setVisibility(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility)).

Comment: This worked for me. As of Jackson 2.0, ObjectMapper#setVisibility takes a PropertyAccessor as the first argument. The equivalent oneliner is  


`myObjectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);`

Comment: @DanRobinson I used same. But actually I am generating yaml file. so for the JSONString as : `{"term":{"call_failed":"true"}}` it is generating yaml structure as: `filter:
  map:
    term:
      map:
        call_failed: "true"`
Why it is generating `map` keyword? How can I remove it ?

Comment: I probably spent 8 hours with this error, not realizing that my getter method did not have "public" on it..so stupid

Comment: I am getting this error while converting ClientResponse to string using object mapper

Comment: You can also add the annotation `@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)` above your class

Answer (score 150):

Add a

> getter

and a

> setter

and the problem is solved.

Comment: Tried many different things, and the solution is as simple as this....and it says it quite clearly: "no properties discovered to create".

Comment: @PhilipRego He means he added a getter and setter for the field.

Comment: I use lombok library, so I just add anotation Getter and Setter. And everything was fine. Thanks.

Comment: yeah, getters and setters are used for Jackson serialization./deserialization

Comment: adding Getters alone solved the issue for me, no need to add setters

Comment: Just add Getters and the problem will be solved.setters are not compulsory

Comment: You can find more information on how to handle this type of error in this blog: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonmappingexception

Answer (score 92):

For Jackson to serialize that class, the `SomeString` field needs to either be `public` (right now it's package level isolation) or you need to define getter and setter methods for it.

Comment: Please note this answer is incorrect -- the field does not *need* to be public or have a getter and setter.  In another answer to this question, I provided an alternative configuration that does not require changes to the original data structure to be (de)serialized.

Comment: The answer is useful, even if not 100% precisely correct. I'd forgotten to put 'public' on my vars, and this pointed that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 42):

The problem in my case was Jackson was trying to serialize an empty object with no attributes nor methods.

As suggested in the exception I added the following line to avoid failure on empty beans:

For Jackson 1.9

```
myObjectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
```

For Jackson 2.X

```
myObjectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
```

You can find a simple example on [jackson disable fail_on_empty_beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261456/jackson-disable-fail-on-empty-beans)

Answer (score 11):

Jackson uses getters and setters serialization./deserialization.
So add getter and setter in your model class.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem for a child class where I had control, object mapper was in a common module and was inaccessible. I solved it by adding this annotation for my child class whose object was to be serialized.

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
```

Answer (score 9):

If you can edit the class containing that object, I usually just add the annotation

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@JsonIgnore 
NonSerializeableClass obj;
```

Comment: This error fires also when your class has a method with name starting with get... For example NonSerializableClass getMyNonSerializableObject(). Jackson tries to serialise it and fails. To resolve this problem just add @JsonIgnore or rename the method.

Comment: Used the older version: `org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore`

Answer (score 8):

This error is also thrown if you forget to add the .build() method onto your return status.

```
return Response.status(Status.OK);         // fails
return Response.status(Status.OK).build(); // works
```

I got the following error without build() method:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.ResponseBuilderImpl
```

Answer (score 7):

SpringBoot2.0 ，I resolve it by follow code:

```
@Bean public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
 return new ObjectMapper().disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);}
```

Comment: you should keep your model has getter and setter methods.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for contributing. Please add an explanation to your answer, so it's clear what the code does, why it works and how it answers OPs question.

Comment: This helped me! But in my opinion, you should inject the ObjectMapper of the context and configure it afterward rather than creating a new one.

Answer (score 5):

I found at least three ways of doing this:

1. Add `public getters` on your entity that you try to serialize;
2. Add an annotation at the top of the entity, if you don't want `public getters`. This will change the default for Jackson from `Visbility=DEFAULT` to `@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)` where any access modifiers are accepted;
3. Change your `ObjectMapper` globally by setting `objectMapperInstance.setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);`. This should be avoided if you don't need this functionality globally.

Choose based on your needs.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with lazy loading via the hibernate proxy object. Got around it by annotating the class having lazy loaded private properties with:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Can you tell me what this exactly does?

Comment: None of the other solutions worked for me. This one solved the problem. Can anyone explain in detail what the above statement does?

Comment: @scarface This simply tells Jackson to exclude the fields `hibernateLazyInitializer` and `handler` from serialization.

Answer (score 4):

I solved with `@Getter` from lombok

Answer (score 4):

Add this in your application properties file

```
spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem may be because you have declared variable as `private`.
If you change it to `public`, it works.

Better option is to use getter and setter methods for it.

This will solve the issue!

Answer (score 3):

For Oracle Java applications, add this after the `ObjectMapper` instantiation:

```
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are the three options:

1. Data/class that's been accessed needs to be `public`
2. If not `public`, add **getters & setters**
3. Or add `@JsonIgnore("context")`

Answer (score 3):

Adding a getter/setter solved this problem for me.
either manually add getter/setter or use Lombok annotations @Getter/@Setter/@Data for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Please use this at class level for the bean:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value={"hibernateLazyInitializer","handler","fieldHandler"})
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had only getters , after adding setters too , problems resolved.

Answer (score 1):

adding setter and getter will also solve the issue as it fixed for me.
 For Ex:

```
public class TestA {
    String SomeString = "asd";

    public String getSomeString () {        return SomeString ;     }

    public void setSomeString (String SS ) {        SomeString = SS ;   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I added getters and setters I was getting the same error. Later I found a bug, that is by Sonar's advice I cgahnged the getters and setters as protected which was causing the issue. Once I fixed that it worked as exppected.

Answer (score 0):

in spring boot 2.2.5

after adding getter and setter

i added @JsonIgnore on top of the field.

Comment: This will ignore the property. If the property to be read, then we should add getters and setters

Answer (score 0):

If you use Lomdok libraray (https://projectlombok.org/) then add `@Data` (https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) annotation to your data object class.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was the annotation `@RestResource(exported = false)` from the `import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource`. Which I forgot to remove.

Also, I got the same error when I forgot to add the class annotation `@XmlRootElement` from the `import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement`.