# How to set visibility for default ObjectMapper used by MappingJackson2JsonView, using Spring ContentNegotiatingViewResolver

Tags: json, spring, jackson

I'd like to do what's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367312/serializing-with-jackson-json-getting-no-serializer-found), namely:

```
objectMapper.setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
```

Unfortunately the Json mapping for my app is done entirely in xml, like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
  <property name="contentNegotiationManager" ref="contentNegotiationManager"/>
  <property name="defaultViews">
    <list>
      <bean name="jsonView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView"/>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

I don't need a custom ObjectMapper, I'd just like to be able to set the visibility of the default ObjectMapper that is used by MappingJackson2JsonView.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the default `ObjectMapper` used by `MappingJackson2JsonView`. It is stored in a `private` field and no methods exist to modify the object.

However, you can declare your own `ObjectMapper` bean and use `MappingJackson2JsonView#setObjectMapper(ObjectMapper)` to have the `View` use your custom `ObjectMapper` bean.

Comment: That what I thought (feared) :) . Many thanks for your helpful and quick response.