# Unable to serialize Object to Json using Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm trying to serialize an object in Java using Jackson, but when I'm trying to serialize it, it gives me this error:

```
No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer
```

[I tried this post, but it didn't help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367312/serializing-with-jackson-json-getting-no-serializer-found)

Here is the class I'm trying to serialize:

```
public class Repository {
    public String name;
    @JsonIgnore   // to avoid recursive calls
    public ArrayList<UserRole> contributors = new ArrayList<UserRole>();
    public User self;
    public ArrayList<FileInfo> files;
    public RepositoryType repositoryType;
    public String path;
}
```

I also tried to create getters/setters for each field but still nothing.

Here is my serialization method:

```
public static String convertObjectToJson(Object object) throws IOException {
        ObjectWriter objectWriter = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        String json = objectWriter.writeValueAsString(object); //error on this line
        return json;
    }
```

Comment: what is `FileInfo`? how do you expect Jackson to serialize it?

Comment: Why shouldn't jackson serialize it ? files field is null when im passing the object to the serializer .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your one of your classes has `java.io.FileDescriptor` reference.

> By default, Jackson will only work with with fields that are either public, or have a public getter methods – serializing an entity that has all fields private or package private will fail

If you look at the source code of `java.io.FileDescriptor` you can [see](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java/io/java.io.FileDescriptor-source.html)
there are private fields without public getters.

You should configure your `objectMapper` visibility to allow access to private fields also.

```
// For jackson 2.*
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);

// For jackson lower than 2
objectMapper.setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
```

Comment: thanks , im not using fileDescriptro , but changing the ObectWriter to ObjectMapper and setting the visibility solved the problem .

Answer (score 0):

I was facing problems to send objects to Thymeleaf template with ResponseEntity it was giving me exception "StackOverFlowError" while serializing and your note " @JsonIgnore   // to avoid recursive calls" solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)