# Apache Camel - Marshal WrappedInputStream to POJO with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, apache-camel

i am developing an Apache Camel Route with enrich EIP. I am calling a web service and trying to convert the response to a Pojo. This is my code snippet.

```
from("direct:getDetailDominio")
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH, simple("${body.principale}"))
            .setBody(constant(null))
            .to("http4:" + dominiUrl + "?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
            .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
```

The fact is that the Body after the service call is wrapped into a WrappedInputStream and Jackson libs seem to do not know how to map that Object. The error is:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream$WrappedInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )
```

I know that i could convert the body to String.class and then convert the POJO, but i refuse to think there is no a standard way to handle this situation. 
Have you any suggestion?
Thanks,
alessio

Comment: I doubt it, since you are getting a stream, you need to convert it to a string.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367312/serializing-with-jackson-json-getting-no-serializer-found

Comment: I had already tried to convert body to String. The result was an exchange body of type byte[], causing a runtime exception.