# Proguard causes Jackson error

Tags: android, jackson, android-proguard, fasterxml

After enabling proguard rules I faced with the following
So error come before sending anything to network.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to convert
>   FormDocTankPermission to RequestBody

caused by

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No
>   serializer found for class FormDocTankPermission and no properties
>   discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable
>   SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)

My class that I send as `@Retrofit.Body` look like following:

```
class FormDocTankPermission  (
        @get:JsonProperty("fuelCardId")
        val fuelCardId: Long,
        @get:JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
        @get:JsonProperty("validityDate")
        val validityDate: Date
)
```

**I assume that somehow `@get:JsonProperty` causes ISSUE**

I cretea Retrofit like this

```
Builder()
.[...]
.addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
```

Proguard rules for Jackson

```
# Jackson
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper {
    public <methods>;
    protected <methods>;
}
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter {
    public ** writeValueAsString(**);
}
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
```

Comment: see  this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8395924/9130109

Answer (score 2):

Proguard may remove default constructor of custom serializers/deserializers.
That rules help me in such case:

```
-keepclassmembers class ** extends com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.** {
   public <init>(...);
}

-keepclassmembers class ** extends com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.** {
   public <init>(...);
}
```

Comment: This was my issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

If it works properly without proguard, you should try the following pro-guard rules:

```
**-keepattributes** Signature,\*Annotation\*,EnclosingMethod
(Because jackson uses annotation)

**-keep** class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; } (Keep everything under the jackson package)

**-dontwarn** com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.** (Do not throw warning from here)

**-dontwarn** com.fasterxml.jackson.** (Do not throw any kind of warning from here)

**-keep** class org.json.JSONObject.** {** put(java.lang.String,java.util.Map);}
```

If you have a custom **Jsonserializer<>** , you have to keep it.

I hope, it helps you.