# Sending user defined class gives InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class... and no properties discovered

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, arraylist

I have a map, **Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();**
I am storing multiple types of data in this map. 1.) Primitive types 2.) User-defined class's object as a value in this map. When I am casting any primitive type value as Object and store in Map, its working fine but not in case of user-defined. While storing user-defined types data in this map, I am getting below error:-

```
**ERROR [WebExceptionHandler] Error occurred while serving request. Response is as [Response(

description=Type definition error: [simple type, class com.yyz.util.Abc];
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException:
  No serializer found for class com.yyz.util.Abc 
  and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer
  (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)

 (through reference chain: com.xyz.api.web.model.BuResponse["rows"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.xyz.api.web.model.BuRow["children"]->java.util.ArrayList[11]->com.com.xyz.api.web.model.BuRow["[anySetter]"]->java.util.HashMap["column6"]), executionTime=0, responseEntity=<204 No Content,{}>,** responseStatus=ResponseStatus(hasError=true, responseKey=process-exception))]
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class com.yyz.util.Abc]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.yyz.util.Abc and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.xyz.api.web.model.BuResponse["rows"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.com.xyz.api.web.model.BuRow["children"]->java.util.ArrayList[11]->com.com.xyz.api.web.model.BuRow["[anySetter]"]->java.util.HashMap["column6"])
      at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:293) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:265) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:119) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) [spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) [spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881) [spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar!/:1.0.0.Final]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855) [spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar!/:1.0.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at com.blackrock.myworld.common.security.xss.XssFilter.doFilter(XssFilter.java:83) [myworld-common-2.9-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.9-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at com.blackrock.myworld.common.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:73) [myworld-common-2.9-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.9-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at com.blackrock.myworld.api.framework.filter.ImitateLoginInInternalFilter.doFilter(ImitateLoginInInternalFilter.java:66) [classes:?]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at com.blackrock.myworld.api.framework.filter.SimpleUserContextFilter.doFilter(SimpleUserContextFilter.java:42) [classes:?]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at com.blackrock.myworld.common.framework.filter.UserContextFilter.doFilter(UserContextFilter.java:74) [myworld-common-2.9-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.9-SNAPSHOT]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78) [wildfly-undertow-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61) [wildfly-undertow-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_20]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_20]
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_20]
**Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException:
No serializer found for class com.yyz.util.Abc and no properties discovered 
to create BeanSerializer
(to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
(through reference chain: com.xyz.api.web.model.BuResponse["rows"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.com.xyz.api.web.model.BuRow["children"]->java.util.ArrayList[11]->com.com.xyz.api.web.model.BuRow["[anySetter]"]->java.util.HashMap["column6"])**
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1191) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:312) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:33) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:718) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.AnyGetterWriter.getAndSerialize(AnyGetterWriter.java:62) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:723) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:119) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:79) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:18) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:119) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:79) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:18) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1396) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:913) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
      at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:286) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
      ... 68 more
```

Can anyone explain why I am getting this error and what is the solution?

```
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "numRecordsFound", "rowViewCount", "buyingUnitRows" })
public class BuResponse extends Response implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5269171275831114276L;

    private final List<BuRow> buRows = new ArrayList<>();

    private long numRecordsFound;

    private long rowViewCount;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "properties", "children", "positionData" })
public class BuRow extends TreeRow {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9087386484833636274L;

    private List<BuRow> children;

    private Map<String, Object> positionData = new HashMap<>();

    private Map<String, Object> properties;

    public Map<String, Object> getPositionData() {
        return positionData;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your `com.yyz.util.Abc` class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serializing with Jackson (JSON) - getting "No serializer found"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367312/serializing-with-jackson-json-getting-no-serializer-found)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Make your field(s) / getter(s) -- public

The exception says your `Abc` class is an empty bean and `SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS` is enabled (by default). For example, this class would be an empty bean for jackson serializer:

```
    public class Abc {
      boolean boo;
    }
```

If you had at least one `public` field, or a public getter, that would avoid the exception:

```
    public class Abc {
      public boolean boo;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you did not attach `com.yyz.util.Abc` class so can not tell the exact reason but ensure that all the getters and setters are present.

Refer this for more :

[Serializing with Jackson (JSON) - getting "No serializer found"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367312/serializing-with-jackson-json-getting-no-serializer-found)