# Jackson custom serializers

Tags: java, json, jackson

Can a single custom serializer be used as both key serializer and normal object serializer?

i.e. sometime use the serializer as a key serializer for serializing map keys while at other time serializing the object normally.

I was facing issues with JsonGenerator object passed to the serializer method.

When used as a key serializer it expects a field name but when using normally, it expects the value.

Comment: Try the following link which can probably has your answer.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367312/serializing-with-jackson-json-getting-no-serializer-found?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same custom serializer but you need to distinguish somehow whether you need to generate property or whole object. `Map` is serialized to `JSON Object` where `Map` keys are converted to `JSON Object` properties. To generate property with `Jackson` we need to use `writeFieldName` method. To distinguish how you would like to use this serialiser in constructor you can provide this information. Example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleModule userModule = new SimpleModule();
        userModule.addSerializer(User.class, new UserJsonSerializer(false));
        userModule.addKeySerializer(User.class, new UserJsonSerializer(true));

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        mapper.registerModule(userModule);

        User user = new User();
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(Collections.singletonMap(user, user)));
    }
}

class User {

    private String firstName = "Tom";
    private String lastName = "Smith";

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}

class UserJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<User> {

    private final boolean generateKey;

    UserJsonSerializer(boolean generateKey) {
        this.generateKey = generateKey;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(User value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
        throws IOException {
        if (generateKey) {
            serializeAsMapKey(value, gen);
        } else {
            serializeAsObject(value, gen);
        }
    }

    private void serializeAsMapKey(User value, JsonGenerator gen) throws IOException {
        gen.writeFieldName(String.join(",", value.getFirstName(), value.getLastName()));
    }

    private void serializeAsObject(User value, JsonGenerator gen) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeFieldName("first");
        gen.writeString(value.getFirstName());
        gen.writeFieldName("last");
        gen.writeString(value.getLastName());
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{
  "Tom,Smith" : {
    "first" : "Tom",
    "last" : "Smith"
  }
}
```

If you do not have any common logic you can just create two separate classes: `UserJsonSerializer` and `UserKeyJsonSerializer` which is an object oriented and clear solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

But I was looking for some direct API provided by Jackson.
I am more interested in it because I want the same serialization logic for key and object.
I have a complex object which happens to contain this object. While creating the key serializer of that complex object I wanted to use the key serializer of this object.

Comment: @amanmehara, I'm not sure it is possible to generate key partially. Creating key value which will represent complex object should be decoupled from `JSON` serialisation. For example: if you have class `A` and class `B` and `A has B` as one of properties you can implement `convertToKey` method for these two classes. Now in class `A` you can call  `b.convertToKey()` and use it to create key for class `A`. When you have this implemented you can implement `AKeySerialiser` for class `A` and implement it like `gen.writeFieldName(a.convertToKey());`. Key generation we delegate to object.