# How to serialize object to json with Jackson, including ArrayList

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have this simple java object

```
public class Order {
    static public class Product {
        public String name;
        public Integer quantity;
        public Float price;
    }
    public String clientName;
    public String clientPhone;
    ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    public Float total;
}
```

I want to serialize it to JSON using Jackson. I do like this:

```
    String _json;
    ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    _json = ow.writeValueAsString(order);
```

but it won't serialie the array list in my order, only the other members.

How do I serialize an object that contains an `ArrayList`? If it's not possible is there another container class that I can use which is easy to serialize?

Comment: Have you tried making the list public?

Comment: @cricket_007 that works, thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [Serializing with Jackson (JSON) - getting “No serializer found”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367312/serializing-with-jackson-json-getting-no-serializer-found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackson depends on public accessors to determine fields to serialize.

Your list is the only field that isn't publicly exposed, so that's why it's hidden in the output