# Deserialize class with @AutoValue annotation during getting from cache in SpringBoot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, deserialization, auto-value

I've created a value class with `com.google.auto.value.AutoValue` annotation:

```
@AutoValue
@JsonDeserialize(builder = AutoValue_Company.Builder.class)
public abstract class Company {

public static Builder newBuilder() {
    return new AutoValue_Company.Builder();
}

@JsonProperty("id")
public abstract long id();

@JsonProperty("description")
public abstract String description();

@JsonProperty("websiteUrl")
public abstract String websiteUrl();

@AutoValue.Builder
public interface Builder {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    Builder id(long id);

    @JsonProperty("description")
    Builder description(String description);

    @JsonProperty("websiteUrl")
    Builder websiteUrl(String url);

    Company build();
}
}
```

Instance of such class is received from service and result is cached in Redis:

```
@Cacheable(value = "company")
public Company getValue(String id)
```

Here is the config of RedisCacheManager:

```
@Bean(name = "valueCacheManager")
public RedisCacheManager valueCacheManager(final RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    final RedisCacheWriter redisCacheWriter = RedisCacheWriter.lockingRedisCacheWriter(connectionFactory);
    RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
            .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer()));
    cacheConfiguration = cacheConfiguration.entryTtl(Duration.ofSeconds(100));
    return new RedisCacheManager(redisCacheWriter, cacheConfiguration);
}
```

As a result the issue that is connected to deserialization:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.test.models.AutoValue_Company and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was found by changing serializer `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer` to `Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Company.class)`

So the cache config now looks like that:

```
@Bean(name = "valueCacheManager")
public RedisCacheManager valueCacheManager(final RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    final RedisCacheWriter redisCacheWriter = RedisCacheWriter.lockingRedisCacheWriter(connectionFactory);
    RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
             .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Company.class)));
    cacheConfiguration = cacheConfiguration.entryTtl(Duration.ofSeconds(100));
    return new RedisCacheManager(redisCacheWriter, cacheConfiguration);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should name your methods using getters convention e.g. `getId()` etc? I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8395924/5909692) is related.