# Simple POST request to Java Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, post

I have created a RestfulWeb Service in Java that is working well with GET requests. However I cannot find some good resource on how to make it accept POST requests.

This is how I run GET

```
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    @GET
    @Path(value = "/ids/{id}")
    public String ids(@PathParam(value = "id") final String id) throws JSONException {
        return getResults("select * from " + id);
    }
```

In order to access this method from web I just go to mywebservice.com/hello/thisismyID and the method receives the "ID".

How would this look if it was to be done with a POST.

Thanks in advance,

-D

Comment: Use `@POST` instead of `@GET`?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194408/how-to-access-parameters-in-a-restful-post-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example

```
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    @POST
    @Path(value = "/ids")
    public String ids(@HeaderParam("id") final String id) throws JSONException {
        return getResults("select * from " + id);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MariuszS can you please share me the URL how to call that post service?

Comment: @Sateesh2607 something like this `curl  -X POST -H "id=foo" http://localhost:8080/hello/ids`

Answer (score 1):

```
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    @POST
    @Path("/ids/{id}")
    public String ids(@PathParam("id") final String id) throws JSONException {
        return getResults("select * from " + id);
    }
}
```

an exhaustive tutorial can be found here: [Vogella_REST](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html#jaxb_project)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194408/how-to-access-parameters-in-a-restful-post-method