# How can I pass multiple parameter to restful webservice using http post

Tags: java, android, rest

I have two array parameters and array of Objects and I want to pass them 
can I use method like this

```
 @POST
 @Path("Test3")
 @Produces("text/plain")
 @Consumes({"application/json"})
  public String Test3(String[] id1,String[] id2 ,Object [] oo) {
        String result = "Hello ";

       ....
       ....
        return result;

    }
```

and what is the corresponding json that I should pass to this method

I try alot of jsons and I always get errors like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  - Error report</title><style type="text/css"><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error</h1><hr/><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b>Internal Server Error</p><p><b>description</b>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init&#40;&#41; for servlet entities.service.ApplicationConfig threw exception</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] Method public java.lang.String entities.service.ItemFacadeREST.Test3&#40;java.lang.String,java.lang.String&#41; on resource class entities.service.ItemFacadeREST contains multiple parameters with no annotation. Unable to resolve the injection source.&#59; source=&#39;ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[application/json], producedTypes=[text/plain], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=MethodHandler{handlerClass=class entities.service.ItemFacadeREST, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@cdf30b]}, handlingMethod=public java.lang.String entities.service.ItemFacadeREST.Test3&#40;java.lang.String,java.lang.String&#41;, parameters=[Parameter [type=class java.lang.String, source=null, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.lang.String, source=null, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class java.lang.String}, nameBindings=[]}&#39;]</pre></p><p><b>note</b> <u>The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  logs.</u></p><hr/><h3>GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0 </h3></body></html>
```

Note : 
I want to call http post from Android

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the JSON being sent in the HTTP Request body is marshaled to the first method parameter.  Your other parameters are not annotated as to where they are coming from in the request, which is why you are getting the error:

```
ItemFacadeREST contains multiple parameters with no annotation.
```

Your best option would be to combine the parameters into a single JSON object; something like:

```
{

    "id1":[
        "string1",
        "string2"
    ],
    "id2":[
        "string3",
        "string4"
    ],
    "oo":[
        {
            "object1":""
        },
        {
            "object2":""
        }
    ]
}
```

And then change your method to:

```
 @POST
 @Path("Test3")
 @Produces("text/plain")
 @Consumes({"application/json"})
  public String Test3(MyJsonObject json) {
        //Parse the JSON object 

    }
```

You will, of course, need to define a class that represents the `MyJsonObject`.

This SO post has an excellent explanation of configuring RESTful services: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8194612/2378728