# How to make post ajax call with JSON data to Jersey rest service?

Tags: java, ajax, post, jersey, jax-rs

I have been through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194408/how-to-access-parameters-in-a-restful-post-method). but this did not helped me out.

I am using jersey lib v1.17.1. 
My jersey rest service:

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/post1")
public ResponseBean post1(@QueryParam("param1")String param1)
{
    return ResponseFactory.createResponse(param1, "TEST", "TEST", null, true);
}
```

url is: `/test/post1`

My ajax call:

```
var d = {"param1":"just a dummy data"};
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "http://localhost:7070/scl/rs/test/post1",
        contentType :"application/json; charSet=UTF-8",
        data : d,
        dataType : "json"
    })
    .done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })
    .fail(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
```

It hits to my rest service but as `param1` I am alway getting null value. The alternate solution is to add JavaBean with `@XMLRootElement` which will marshal/unmarshal the java object to json and vice versa, but I do not want to use this.
Is there any way to post data and receive it using appropriate annotation like `@QueryParam` or something like that ?
Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server-side code should be like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/post1")
public ResponseBean post1(Data param1)
{
    return ResponseFactory.createResponse(param1, "TEST", "TEST", null, true);
}
```

where `Data` is a (POJO) class annotated with `@XmlRootElement` and corresponds to the JSON data what your client will send (ie, have a `param1` field with getter and setter). The JAX-RS implementation will unmarshall the body of the POST into an instance of `Data`.

`@QueryParam` annotation is used ot retrieve the query params in a (usually) `GET` requests. Query params are the params after the question mark (`?`). Eg: `@QueryParam("start") String start` will map be set to `1` when the following request is processed: `GET http://foo.com/bar?start=1`, but this is not what you're doing in your case, AFAICS.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can simply take Post dat as a string and then you can parse it using JSONObject.
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/post1")
    public Response postStrMsg(String msg) {
        String output = "POST:Jersey say : " + msg;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the @XMLRootElement is the way to do that since the json must be unmarshaled before you can use any of its elements.