# How to send a post request with multiple parameters

Tags: java, post, resttemplate

I have a project where we call a GET method from Java Script : the method called is below :

```
public
@ResponseBody
Map run( @RequestParam Map map, HttpServletRequest request,   HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

}
```

Now I am writing a Micro service to do the work which is done inside the above method . And the requirement is this method will call the micro-service .The only thing I am stuck with is passing the  (HttpServletRequest request,   HttpServletResponse response)  to the method in micro-service I am calling as they have some data in there which will be used.

My method definition in micro-service looks like :

```
@POST
@Path("/myPostCall")
public String myPostCall(Map map,HttpServletRequest request,       HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
}
```

Now I am trying to call this by

```
 RestTemplate abc = new RestTemplate();
abc.postForObject("http://localhost:8008/report/run", report1, String.class);
```

It gives me 422 error . But If I remove the request,response parameters in micro-service method . it runs good . But I need them too . Because they have data in it . Is there something out of my understanding .

Comment: Look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194408/how-to-access-parameters-in-a-restful-post-method/8194612#8194612

Comment: thanks ! I could send the request with RESTTEMPLATE postForObject . but still having HttpServletRequest  and HttpServletResponse  are creating problems.

Comment: Why do want want them as request parameters in method ? You can use them as context parameters with **@Context** annotation.

Comment: Hey Thanks ! I have edited the question to make it clear

Comment: Have u tried with @Context annotation ? Is that useful for u ?

Comment: Hey , I think yes . At least it enters the method now .

Comment: What is the status then ? R u succeed in ur task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use them as private variables in class as :

```
@Context 
private HttpServletRequest request;
@Context 
private HttpServletResponse response;
```

**OR**

```
@POST
@Path("/myPostCall")
public String myPostCall(..., @Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
    //do some stuff
}
```

Comment: @Abhishek Bhandari Good to know this helps you.