# Posting Json data from browser to Java application

Tags: javascript, java, json, web-services, rest

Im currently trying to figure out what process to follow in terms of posting data from my browser using JavaScript to a Java application.

**JavaScript Post function**

```
 xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var url = "http://localhost:9200/test/mytest";
 xhr.open("POST", url, true);
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
 var data = JSON.stringify({"test" : testdata123});
 xhr.send(data);
```

I would like to consume the above Json data in a java application using rest. How do i go about setting this up?

Comment: JSON.parse(json); Use this to parse json

Comment: how do I consume this data in a java application? do i need to create a rest service in java?. I am new to this so im very confused.

Comment: Yes, using spring or servlet you can create rest web service

Comment: @RestController Annotation will be used ...in case of spring

Comment: Thank you, so i will post to a servlet? and then consume with java application from servlet?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a duplicate of 
[How to consume json parameter in java restful service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983048/how-to-consume-json-parameter-in-java-restful-service)

As per JSR 311, you may use @Consumes annotation accepting MIME type of application/json to consume the data in your java application.