# How does @Consume populate variables and objects?

Tags: java, rest, api

I'm trying to process an incoming request that is a JSON. The code below is a sample:

```
@Post
@Path("somePath")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response myService(requestDTO requestBody){
        //Doing Stuff
}
```

My DTO class is essentially this:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class RequestDTO{
    private Object object;

    public Object getter(){}
    public void setter(){}
}
```

My question is how does the @Consumes annotation know to take the information in the request JSON and place it into the object of my DTO? How would this work if I had multiple variables in my DTO? Or multiple levels in my request body (Object inside Objects, etc)?

Sorry for such a general question, but I'm having a hard time understanding this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question. This answer here is a good explanation of how to properly use the @Consumes annotation.

[How to consume json parameter in java restful service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983048/how-to-consume-json-parameter-in-java-restful-service)