# JSON Post Response from JSON Post Request

Tags: java, json, rest, post

I have created a REST webservice which gives me 
'GET JSON Response' as :

```
 {
        "payload": {
            "RFID": "E2005180040F003122202E5F",
            "chassisNumber": "4654689761",
            "vehicleNumber": "TN 01 1991"
        },
        "success": "true"
    }
```

Now I want Post Response from below Post Request :

```
Vehicle tag Request
{
  "vehicle_no": "TN07B0054"
 }
```

I have created the post method but it takes the whole thing as argument.

How to take vehicle argument as "TN07B0054" only from the Vehicle tag request.

Below is the `POST` response when I give above Vehicle Tag Request :

```
{
    "payload": {
        "vehicleNumber": "\"vehicle_no\": \"TN 07 B 0054\""
    },
    "success": "false"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a entity named *VehicleTagRequest*

```
public class VehicleTagRequest {
    private String vehicle_no;

    public String getVehicle_no() {
        return vehicle_no;
    }

    public void setVehicle_no(String vehicle_no) {
        this.vehicle_no = vehicle_no;
    }
}
```

Easiest way to deserialise your string to above java object is to use **Jackson library** (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

If you are *Maven* for dependency management, you can add dependency like below in your **pom.xml** (this step is not required if you are maintaining your dependencies locally)

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0.pr4</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Now comes deserialisation of your vehicle tag request json**

Deserialisation using Jackson is done using `ObjectMapper API` if you are not using annotations,
I have made a sample code snippet attached below-

```
public class VehicleSerialisation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String vehicle = "{\"vehicle_no\": \"TN07B0054\"}";

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        VehicleTagRequest vehicleTagRequest = null;
        try {
            vehicleTagRequest = objectMapper.readValue(vehicle, VehicleTagRequest.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.print(vehicleTagRequest.getVehicle_no());
    }
}
```

You can then use the `vehicleTagRequest.getVehicle_no()` to form your request of *GET JSON Response*

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help. I tried your answer but there was no success. I followed below link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194408/how-to-access-parameters-in-a-restful-post-method
and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid Json

```
{
    "payload": {
        "vehicleNumber": "\"vehicle_no\": \"TN 07 B 0054\""
    },
    "success": "false"
}
```

Without escape char

```
{
    "payload": {
        "vehicleNumber": "vehicle_no": "TN 07 B 0054"
    },
    "success": "false"
}
```

You can use like this

```
{
        "payload": {
            "vehicleNumber": {
          "vehicle_no": "TN 07 B 0054"
              }
        },
        "success": "false"
    }
```

And your POJO should be like

```
public class MyPojo
{
    private Payload payload;

    private String success;

    public Payload getPayload ()
    {
        return payload;
    }

    public void setPayload (Payload payload)
    {
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    public String getSuccess ()
    {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess (String success)
    {
        this.success = success;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [payload = "+payload+", success = "+success+"]";
    }
}
```