# Why does converting this Python POST request to Java not work?

Tags: java, android, python, http, post

I'm trying to convert this Python code using the Python Requests HTTP library into Java code (for Android).

```
import requests
payload = {"attr[val1]":123,
           "attr[val2]":456,
           "time":0,
           "name":"Foo","surname":"Bar"}

r = requests.post("http://jakiro.herokuapp.com/api", data=payload)
r.status_code
r.text
```

This is what I've done so far:

```
protected void sendJson() {
    Thread t = new Thread() {

        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare(); //For Preparing Message Pool for the child Thread
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit
            HttpResponse response;
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            try {
                Log.v("SOMETHING_NAME3", "Creating POST");
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://jakiro.herokuapp.com/api");
                json.put(MessageAttribute.SURNAME, "Bar");
                json.put(MessageAttribute.VAL1, 123);
                json.put(MessageAttribute.VAL2, 456);
                json.put(MessageAttribute.name, "Foo");
                json.put(MessageAttribute.TIME, 0);
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity( json.toString() );
                se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                post.setEntity(se);
                response = client.execute(post);

                /*Checking response */
                if(response!=null){
                    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); //Get the data in the entity
                    String foo = convertStreamToString(in);
                    Log.v("SOMETHING_NAME2", foo); // Gives me "Bad request"
                }

            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.v("SOMETHING_NAME", "Cannot Establish Connection");
            }

            Looper.loop(); //Loop in the message queue
        }
    };

    t.start();
}
```

I've checked the response with `response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()` and I get back a 400 from the server. The Python code *works* fine, but in Java on an Android device it doesn't. I can't see to figure out why though.

Comment: In the Python code, `data` is percent-encoded. It's not encoded with JSON.

Comment: Interesting, Hhw would I convert that object to be percent-encoded then?

Comment: No clue, I don't work with Java. I'd imagine something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120220/how-to-use-parameters-with-httppost

Comment: @Blender Great, I got it working! If you could convert your comment to an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Blender's link was the correct solution at the link: [How to use parameters with HttpPost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120220/how-to-use-parameters-with-httppost)

The correct way to url-encode was to create `BasicNameValuePairs` and encode that as such:

```
postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", "param1_value"));
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2", "param2_value"));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
```