# How can we do HTTP POST request by adding query parameters in Java?

Tags: java, rest

Here I am trying to post some data to Rest API by adding query parameters using Java but getting response saying bad request.

When I test it from SOAPUI or CURL commands it is working fine.[image][image]

```
package com.anergroup;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class RestRequestURL {
    public void TestRestRequest(){
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
        builder.setScheme("http").setHost("hostname")
        .setPort(8080)
        .setPath("/oauth/check_token")
        .setParameter("token", "7e9e5b81-1009-49cb-b71f-f418c6b1db3f");

        URI uri;

        try {
            uri = builder.build();
            System.out.println("URL Token1 : "+uri);
              HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                System.out.println("URL Token : "+response);
        } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1, Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, Pragma: no-cache, Expires: 0, X-Frame-Options: DENY, X-Application-Context: api-gateway-uaa:dev:8080, Cache-Control: no-store, Pragma: no-cache, Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8, Transfer-Encoding: chunked, Date: Wed, 25 May 2016 15:08:27 GMT, Connection: close]
```

Comment: do you know difference between GET and POST?

Comment: Yes. GET - Requests data from a specified resource,
POST - Submits data to be processed to a specified resource. In my case, I am sending token as query parameter and getting response in JSON format.

Comment: Please let me know if I am doing any mistake?

Comment: GET transfers arguments in URL, POST sends data as part of the message body

Comment: here is how you should pass token http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120220/how-to-use-parameters-with-httppost

Comment: Can you please modify my code to make it work? I tried in many ways to pass parameters and keep trying

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and let you know

Comment: Sorry, Getting same response saying bad request.

Comment: Thanks Lashane, your answer helped. I tried this using get it worked fine. But I don't why it is supporting POST and GET also.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to just be able to send a POST request to a Rest API URL, please check the example code at [How to send a POST reqeust in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/) and try one of the implementations given there.

Comment: I tried but same response. here my goal is to do REST service POST request by adding query parameters.

Comment: I tried get method from the given and it worked fine. thanks for you help Chetan.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to actually add the token attribute to the payload of the post, not as a URL argument.  That is what the -d option is doing on the Curl.

Easy way to do that is to do something like this

```
List<NameValuePair> data = new new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token","7e9e5b81-1009-49cb-b71f-f418c6b1db3f"));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEnity(data));
```

[Edit] Looks like you may also need to set the content-type header. Curl adds " content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded" automatically, so you will need to add this to the post as well.

```
httppost.addHeader(new BasicHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
```

Comment: Same Responce, HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1, Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, Pragma: no-cache, Expires: 0, X-Frame-Options: DENY, X-Application-Context: api-gateway-uaa:dev:8080, Cache-Control: no-store, Pragma: no-cache, Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8, Transfer-Encoding: chunked, Date: Wed, 25 May 2016 16:05:06 GMT, Connection: close]

Comment: Add this to the startup arguments, it will output all the data sent on the line, and maybe you can see whats wrong with the request  -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime=true -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http=DEBUG