# GraphQL client for java application

Tags: java, spring, graphql, graphqlclient

I need a graphQL client for java spring application to communicate with another microservice based on graphQL API. I know about Apollo Android but it seems to be not implemented with maven (maybe you know some links or examples with maven etc). Any ideas and suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: another simple way might be to just use POSTMan to generate the code for you in java, tweak a little here and there and use it, but libraries such as apollos and one mentioned in the answer below have far fancier bells and whistles like caching and type system support. 

Answer (score -1):

I've found few links which might be helpful to you.

1. A graphql client library for microservices communication [graphql-spring-webclient](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-webclient)
2. There is another question which i believe uses native graphql maven dependency for client call [Make a POST call to GraphQL API programmatically using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59055068/make-a-post-call-to-graphql-api-programmatically-using-java)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)