# How to web scrape on server side?

Tags: java, javascript, automation, web-scraping

I'm not sure if the title says what I needed. But that's the best way I can put it.

*My requirement:* I want to check if a series of engine numbers (of vehicles) are registered with the local transportation authority. They have provide a web-interface for this task, but I can only check for a single engine number at once. Usually I need to check over 200 numbers. So, its a humongous task to check each one individually.

A couple of years ago, I have created a small standalone python script to do this automatically using web scraping, but now I want to do this on a server.

A user gives all the numbers in the text file which they upload/paste the contents in to a text field. Then I'll have to submit the form on the transportation website (using web scraping) for each number and display a final status for all of them.

What I want to know is how to do this on a server? What technologies could be helpful. I'm comfortable with Java & JavaScript. I don't know PHP (But i can learn if needed). I don't have slightest Idea how to do this on server side. Any Ideas and Help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Alright! I don't know how to ask! A down vote don't solve my problem right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java has a library called JSoup, which provides a mostly-familiar api that uses css selectors.

And obviously there are built-in functions that can get you the html from a given URL.

Put those together and you've got a server-side scraper

[edit]
Your question, on a re-read, isn't just about scraping -- it's about how to automatically submit an html form from within Java to an external server. This is an interesting question, one I've wondered myself.

this may be an answer: [How to send post form with java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581550/how-to-send-post-form-with-java)